# Is the language of the Notice grammatically correct or not?

Tags: passive-voice, politeness

A notice begins as follows:

> It is hereby informed that a meeting of LPLD committee will be held on 12/12/12 at 12 noon in the chamber of BDO...All the members of the committee are requested to make it convenient to attend the meeting without fail

My questions are:

1. Is the language of the  Notice grammatically correct or not?
2. Is there any indecency when the convenor of the meeting sends this notice to his higher official who is also a member of the committee  ?

Comment: This sounds to me as [Legal English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_English). And for me, it is best to treat Legal English separately from Standard English. (For me, the answers are yes and no--it just means that the meeting is mandatory to all the members.)

Comment: Please give me a proper answer.

Comment: Being a non-native speaker, and not familiar with Legal English, I'm afraid that I don't know much enough to provide a good and appropriate answer. All I can do is giving the information I have and some of my opinions. However, please wait for others here. I'm certain that there are many others who can provide you the appropriate ones.

Comment: It's grammatically correct, although few native speakers would phrase such a notice that way. Can you edit your question to indicate why you think it might be grammatically incorrect? Also, why do you think it could be disrespectful to the superior official? It will be easier for us to answer your question if we understand exactly what causes you to wonder about the grammar or propriety of the notice.

Comment: It is grammatically incorrect: *inform*, in this sense, requires two complements, a person and a content, and only the person can act as subject of a passive construction. *A informs B that C* → B is informed [by A] that C*

Comment: Eh, good catch @StoneyB. I must have read "informed" as "announced" somehow.

Comment: I'd skip the 'roundabout wording.  If the meeting is mandatory then say so; and tell me what the consequences of missing it will be.

Comment: Hi EuReka, welcome to ELL! As it stands this question is off-topic because we do not accept proofreading unless a specific area of concern is pointed out. "Is this piece of text grammatical" is not acceptable. Also, we can't speak to proper workplace behavior; you might try another SE site, [The Workplace](workplace.stackexchange.com) for that question.

Answer (score 2):

There are several grammar errors here.

"It is hereby informed that a meeting ... will be held ..."

"... is ... informed" is passive voice. So the thing being informed is "it". But who or what is "it"? That is, who or what is being informed? Probably not any "it" but the person the notice was sent to, that is, "you". The writer probably intended to say, "You are hereby informed that ..."

"LPLD committee" should be "the LPLD committee". That's a description of something -- some sort of committee -- and not a proper noun, so it requires an article (or one of the adjectives that can substitute for an article).

Finally, "all members are requested to make it convenient" is grammatically correct but does not make sense. How would the members make it convenient to attend when the place and time of the meeting have already been set? The person scheduling the meeting could make it convenient; the people invited probably cannot. I suppose you could say that the intent is that the committee members should arrange their personal schedules so that this meeting can conveniently be fit in, but this is just not a common way to express that idea. What the writer presumably means is that the members should be sure to attend or should make an effort to attend, or maybe possibly that the members should attend if it is convenient.

"Indecent" means obscene, immodest, or offensive in a sexual way. So it would not be indecent for the person arranging this meeting to send such a notice to a higher official unless she includes nude photos of herself with the notice. :-) I think you meant something more like "inappropriate". In that case, perhaps saying "requested to attend ... without fail" would be inappropriate, as you are then essentially giving orders to a superior. Drop the "without fail" and there would be nothing wrong with sending the notice to your boss.

Comment: I agree with many of your points with two minor exceptions.  1) with regards to "all members are requested to make it convenient", context proves that the intended meaning is that the informed members must attend, so they should make an effort to fit it in their schedule.  2) I would say that the notices is NOT inappropriate given the presumed official-ness.  If you have the authority to set up the meeting, and all members must attend, then you also have the authority notify them that they must attend.

Comment: @doc If by the first part you mean that my comment about "members should attend if it is convenient" is not valid in context: true. I was parsing the specific words there and not the larger context.

Comment: @doc I think that in general, telling your boss, "you are required to do this" could be considered insubordinate if you are the originator of the message. If you are passing on a message from someone higher ranking than your boss, that would be different. But even if I was responsible for scheduling meetings of some committee, I wouldn't consider it appropriate to decide on my own that my boss is required to attend this meeting and to tell him so. I don't have that authority. But regardless, this is a question of office protocol, not of language, so I don't want to argue about it here.

Answer (score -1):

> We hereby inform you that a meeting of LPLD committee will be held on 12/12/12 at 12 noon in the chamber of BDO...All the members of the committee are requested to make it convenient to attend the meeting without fail.

The sentence is question is re-phrased in an active voice.

> It is hereby informed **you** that a meeting of LPLD committee will be held on 12/12/12 at 12 noon in the chamber of BDO...All the members of the committee are requested to make it convenient to attend the meeting without fail.

If you change it back to a passive voice sentence and drop the indirect object, **you**, you will end up with a sentence like the one in question.

Comment: "It is hereby informed you" is not grammatical. The first example ("We hereby inform you"), however, is OK.